# How do I Pick the best performer from a set using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Given a set `var battingContribution = IQueryable<Player, Runs>` (Basically a list of players and their total batting score) and another set `var bowlingContribution = IQueryable<Player, Runs>`, how do I pick whose net contribution was the best such that the player whose batting score minus the bowling score results in the highest net total?

Comment: There is no `IQueryable` that accepts two type parameters. What are you really using?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: `IDictionary` probably.

Comment: It's actually an anonymous type. I just threw some pseudocode up there to get my point across. I could use a Dictionary I suppose but I haven't reached a point where I'm optimising my code yet; just trying to get the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works only for `Players` that are in both Contributions (although I don't know an IQueryable with two type params):

```
var BestPlayer = (from a in (from bt in battingContribution from bw in BowlingContribution where bt.Player == bw.Player select new { Player = bt.Player, Diff = bt.Runs - bw.Runs)) orderby a.Diff descending select a).First().Player;
```

MSDN reference to Linq samples see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

EDIT - as per comment from OP for completeness:

```
var BestPlayer = (from a in (from bt in batRuns from bw in bowlRuns where bt.Player == bw.Player select new { Player = bt.Player, Diff = bt.Runs - bw.Runs}) orderby a.Diff descending select a).First();
```

Comment: Slight edit to what you've provided:   
`var BestPlayer = (from a in (from bt in batRuns from bw in bowlRuns where bt.Player == bw.Player select new { Player = bt.Player, Diff = bt.Runs - bw.Runs}) orderby a.Diff descending select a).First();`  
But that definitely works!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have `IDictionary<Player, Runs>` instead of `IQueryable` (which doesn't have two type parameters):

```
// Just to make sure that we don't get exceptions if a player is only in one
// of the two collections -- you might want to handle this case differently
var players = battingContribution.Keys.Intersect(bowlingContribution.Keys);

// Put each player and their performance into what is essentialy a tuple
var performance = players.Select(p => 
    new {
        Player = p,
        Performance = battingContribution[p] - bowlingContribution[p]
    });

// Sorting
var orderedPerformance = performance.OrderByDescending(item => item.Performance);

// Selecting best performer
var bestPerformer = orderedPerformance.First().Player;
```

You can chain these together for terseness if you prefer.